# Shape changing when applying conv2d inside a block

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am applying [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/super-resolution-gan-srgan-5e10438aec0c) research paper using tensorflow, I am building a generator using the sequential API.

This is the code which I have the issue with:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,BatchNormalization,Input,PReLU
from operations import SubPixelConv2d

def make_generator():

    w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02)
    g_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
    x_in = Input(shape=(64,64,3)) # Shape : (None,64,64,3)
    print(x_in.shape)
    n = Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu', \
        kernel_initializer=w_init,data_format="channels_last",input_shape=(64,64,3))(x_in) # TODO: Fix shape current shape: (?,60,60,64)
    n = PReLU()(n)
    temp = n
    print(x_in.shape)

    # Residual Block 
    for i in range(15):
        nn = Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same', \
        input_shape=(64,64,3))(n)
        print(nn.shape)
        nn = BatchNormalization(gamma_initializer=g_init)(nn)
        nn = PReLU()(nn)
        nn = Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu', \
        kernel_initializer=w_init,data_format="channels_last",input_shape=(64,64,3))(nn)
        nn = BatchNormalization(gamma_initializer=g_init)(nn)
        nn = tf.add_n([n,nn])
        n = nn
```

I got the `ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 62 and 64. Shapes are [?,62,62,64] and [?,64,64,64].`

That's why I'm printing out the shapes to see where the problem is.

This is the o/p of the shapes:

```
(None, 64, 64, 3)
2020-05-16 22:19:34.555494: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-05-16 22:19:34.555528: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-05-16 22:19:34.555548: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (joyarch): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-05-16 22:19:34.555777: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-05-16 22:19:34.595735: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU Frequency: 1800000000 Hz
2020-05-16 22:19:34.596281: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f3328000b60 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-05-16 22:19:34.596308: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
(None, 64, 64, 3)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
(None, 64, 64, 64)
```

Why is the shape changing ?

**What I've tried**

Remove `kernel_initializer` and `data_format` parameters from the `Conv2D` layer inside the blocks.

I am not able to figure what is causing this change.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, I was not using the correct `kernel_size` for the convolution layers as given on the paper.